# PHPMailer and outlook 365 sometimes works

Tags: php, outlook, phpmailer

Without changing any code, sometimes PHPMailer with SMTP and outlook 365 works and sometimes it won't.
I tried the SMTPDebug and compare the results but they are almost the same.
It seems to be failing at Authentication as you can see at the bottom.

Please help!

Here the SMTPDebug >= 4

**Success**

```
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 13 Sep 2017 15:28:47 +0000 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220 SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 13 Sep 2017 15:28:47 +0000 "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 13 Sep 2017 15:28:47 +0000
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 157286400 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-DSN "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-STARTTLS "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-STARTTLS "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-STARTTLS "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-STARTTLS 250-8BITMIME "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-STARTTLS 250-8BITMIME "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-BINARYMIME "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-STARTTLS 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-STARTTLS 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-CHUNKING "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-STARTTLS 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-STARTTLS 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 SMTPUTF8 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-STARTTLS 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-STARTTLS 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 157286400 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-DSN "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2 250-8BITMIME "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2 250-8BITMIME "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-BINARYMIME "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-CHUNKING "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 SMTPUTF8 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-SC1P215CA0018.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "235 2.7.0 Authentication successful target host BLUPR16MB0179.namprd16.prod.outlook.com "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "235 2.7.0 Authentication successful target host BLUPR16MB0179.namprd16.prod.outlook.com "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 2.1.0 Sender OK "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250 2.1.0 Sender OK "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.1.0 Sender OK
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 2.1.5 Recipient OK "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250 2.1.5 Recipient OK "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "354 Start mail input; end with . "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "354 Start mail input; end with . "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:354 Start mail input; end with .
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 2.6.0 [InternalId=93054761437225, Hostname=BLUPR16MB0179.namprd16.prod.outlook.com] 3346 bytes in 0.985, 3.315 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250 2.6.0 [InternalId=93054761437225, Hostname=BLUPR16MB0179.namprd16.prod.outlook.com] 3346 bytes in 0.985, 3.315 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.6.0 [InternalId=93054761437225, Hostname=BLUPR16MB0179.namprd16.prod.outlook.com] 3346 bytes in 0.985, 3.315 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery
```

**Error**

```
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 13 Sep 2017 15:21:14 +0000 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220 SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 13 Sep 2017 15:21:14 +0000 "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 13 Sep 2017 15:21:14 +0000
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 157286400 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-DSN "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-STARTTLS "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-STARTTLS "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-STARTTLS "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-STARTTLS 250-8BITMIME "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-STARTTLS 250-8BITMIME "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-BINARYMIME "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-STARTTLS 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-STARTTLS 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-CHUNKING "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-STARTTLS 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-STARTTLS 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 SMTPUTF8 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-STARTTLS 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-STARTTLS 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 157286400 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-DSN "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2 250-8BITMIME "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2 250-8BITMIME "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-BINARYMIME "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-CHUNKING "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 SMTPUTF8 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-SC1P15201CA0047.outlook.office365.com Hello [X.X.X.X] 250-SIZE 157286400 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 "
SMTP -> ERROR: Password not accepted from server:
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "235 2.7.0 Authentication successful target host CY1PR16MB0187.namprd16.prod.outlook.com "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "235 2.7.0 Authentication successful target host CY1PR16MB0187.namprd16.prod.outlook.com "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:235 2.7.0 Authentication successful target host CY1PR16MB0187.namprd16.prod.outlook.com
SMTP -> ERROR: RSET failed: 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful target host CY1PR16MB0187.namprd16.prod.outlook.com
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

**Send mail function**

```
public function enviarCorreo($para, $cc = NULL, $nombre_desde, $asunto, $cuerpo, $adjunto)
{
    $bd = new DB;
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../include/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');

    try {
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "No se pudo instanciar el objeto Mail: ".$e->getMessage()."<br>";
    }

    $sqlParamCorreo = $bd->query("SELECT * FROM parametros") or die ("Error parametros: ".mysql_error());

    if($sqlParamCorreo)
        $correo = $bd->fetchObj();  
    else
        $correo = NULL;

    $mail->SetLanguage("es", 'includes/phpMailer/language/');
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;

    $mail->Host = $correo->host_correo; // smtp.office365.com

    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";

    $mail->Port = $correo->puerto_correo; // 587

    $mail->Username = $correo->usuario_correo;
    $mail->Password = $correo->pass_correo;

    $mail->SetFrom($correo->usuario_correo, $nombre_desde);
    $mail->Subject  = $asunto;

    foreach($para as $destino) {
        $mail->AddAddress($destino);
    }

    if(!is_null($cc)) {
        foreach($cc as $destino_cc) {
            $mail->AddCC($destino_cc);
        }
    }

    if(!is_null($adjunto)) {
        $aux = explode("_",$adjunto);
        $nombre = "OC_".$aux[1]."_".$aux[2];
        $mail->AddAttachment($adjunto, $nombre);    
    }

    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    $mail->Body = $cuerpo;

    if(!$mail->Send())
        return $mail->ErrorInfo;

    else
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Did you notice that your authentication failed? Password was rejected

Comment: I would take a closer look at your sql. You pull your password from your SQL database

Comment: Also, I would take a look at your error log. I'm not entirely sure about this, but I think ___you just leaked a password/hash publically___

Comment: @DaMaxContent thank you for your answare. I noticed authentication failed. While I did this tests, I dumped the database params and allways got correct data. I don't see where I leaked the password

Comment: `334 VXNlcm5hbWU6` seems a lot like some sort of hash/key/password

Comment: It doesn't help that you're running a *very* old version of PHPMailer. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and try again. `SMTPDebug = 2` is plenty to debug this level of problem; 4 is just too noisy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated PHPMailer from 5.2 to 6
Now it is working. Thank you [Synchro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/333340/synchro)
I contacted microsoft support before update... and they said it was my app problem